# Is it ok to overwrite Bootstrap V4's preset CSS, which is set by Reboot, with !important?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Sorry for this noob question, but frontend development is so confusing.

Bootstrap v4.0.0-alpha.5 uses something called "Reboot" which sets some defaults on it's own ([see here](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/reboot/#page-defaults)). It says: "For safety, the `<body>` has a declared background-color, defaulting to #fff."

So to overwrite it I used:

```
html, body {
 background-color: $main-background-color !important;
}
```

But I read that using `!important` is considered to be a bad practice. Is this statement also correct in this case, when it only applies to the body-tag?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you look into the partial `/scss/_bootstrap.scss` (which pulls together all other partials in the correct sequence) you'll see the following at the top. Meaning that partial `/scss/_custom.scss` is parsed before partial `/scss/_variables.scss`. :

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "custom";
@import "variables";
```

If you look into the partial named `/scss/_variables.scss` you'll see a line :

```
$body-bg:    #fff !default;
```

`!default` equals fall-back in sass/scss. So if no value was assigned to variable `$body_bg` prior to this specific line, it will be defaulted to `#fff`. When the variable `$body_bg` already has a value assigned when this line is encountered, its value will not be reassigned. And the line in `/scss/_variables.scss` is skipped.

So the proper way to do what you want is to :
1) open the partial named `scss/_custom.scss` in an editor. Because it's parsed before all other partials (inluding /scss/_variables.scss).
2) copy+paste the line with the variable named `$body_bg` from the partial `scss/_variables.scss` into `/scss/_custom.scss`.
3) Change the value `#fff` into whatever you want.
4) Remove the word `!default` (from the line in `/scss/_custom.scss`).
5) Save `/scss/custom.scss` and recompile `/scss/bootstrap.scss`.

You should do it like this with all variables found in `/scss/_variables.scss`.
**EDIT:** I meant to say: When you want to make changes to shipped Bootstrap variables (in `scss/_variables.scss`) you should do it like this. (English is not my native language.)

In the partial `/scss/_reboot.scss` (parsed after `/scss/_variables.scss`) the background will be set to whatever is in variable `$body_bg`. :

```
body {
  // Make the `body` use the `font-size-root`
  font-family: $font-family-base;
  font-size: $font-size-base;
  line-height: $line-height-base;
  // Go easy on the eyes and use something other than `#000` for text
  color: $body-color;
  // By default, `<body>` has no `background-color` so we set one as a best practice.
  background-color: $body-bg;
}
```

When a variable in `/scss/_variables.scss` doesn't have a `!default` flag but one is really required, so that it can be overridden from `/scss/_custom.scss`, then you need to open an issue at the Github repo and discuss/request.

Comment: Now that's a detailed answer, thanks! Do you know how to handle the case if we want to load Bootstrap via CDN where $body-color is already preset? !important then seems like the proper way, am i right?

Comment: Yes I'm afraid so. Once the css is compiled from the scss.

Comment: Hit enter too quickly.

Comment: You could also override the colour by adding/injecting a stylesheet with all your corrections (or between <style></style>-tags) **right after** loading from the CDN.

Comment: But you risk that the white background is still visible in a flash before your preferred background colour is applied. If you choosed to resolve this with ``!important``, than insert a tiny stylesheet with the background correction **before** loading the stylesheet from the CDN.